# Repeater ItemTemplate Container.DataItem is an array

Tags: asp.net

I have a service that has List data returned..  One of the columns in the "class" is also a list.  The ParamName and ParamValue actually need to come from the list Parameters.

Can I put a repeater inside a ItemTemplate?  I'm unable to get it to work if so, please point me the right direction.

```
<asp:Repeater id="RepeaterData" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Name</b></td>
            <td><b>CreatedDate</b></td>
            <td><b>ParamName</b></td>
            <td><b>ParamValue</b></td>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FullName") %></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CreatedDate") %></td>
        <td>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="RepeateParameters" DataSource="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Parameters") %>">
            <ItemTemplate><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ParamName") %><br /></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="Repeater1" DataSource="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Parameters") %>">
            <ItemTemplate><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ParamValue") %><br /></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easly use a Nested Repeater. If it is a List within a List you do not even need to make modifications to the code behind. This example uses a Strongly Typed Repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" ItemType="MyNameSpace.TestClass">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <%# Item.Name %>

        <ul>
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" ItemType="MyNameSpace.TestClass" DataSource='<%# Item.NestedList %>'>
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <li><%# Item.ID %> <%# Item.Date.ToShortDateString() %></li>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>

        <hr />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The class just to make the demo complete.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public List<TestClass> NestedList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've always loaded from server side code to the repeater..  Moving to the ItemType instead, helps a lot and worked out best.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was the final code:

```
<asp:Repeater id="RepeaterData" runat="server" ItemType="accounts.AuditEntry">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><b>UsersFullName</b></td>
            <td><b>CreatedDate</b></td>
            <td><b>ParamName</b></td>
            <td><b>ParamValue</b></td>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><%# Item.UsersFullName %></td>
            <td><%# Item.CreatedDate %></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" ItemType="accounts.ParamInfo" DataSource='<%# Item.Parameters %>'>
                <ItemTemplate><%# Item.ParamName %><br /></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server" ItemType="accounts.ParamInfo" DataSource='<%# Item.Parameters %>'>
                <ItemTemplate><%# Item.ParamValue %><br /></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```